# Intent from Broadcast receiver to an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I have an app, that send SMS when button is clicked. After thet I am expecting a answer SMS, so it goes like this:

1. Button click -> SMS is send (done)
2. SMS reciver is listening for incoming SMS (done)
3. After SMS is recived, Reciver is extracting Text from SMS and saves it to the text file on sdcard (done)
4. After text is copied, i need to start new activity (not done)

So can i start new activity from `BroadcastReceiver` after recived SMS is proccessed?

Comment: what problem do you face in starting an activity?

Comment: what you have to do for start activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from receiver you can start the activity like this:

```
Intent launch = new Intent(context, ActivityToLaunch.class);
launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(launch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Yes. You can start an activity in your `BroadcastReceiver`.